# Java equivalent of GetPositionFromCharIndex

Tags: c#, java

Is there an equivalent in Java Swing/AWT of the [TextBoxBase.GetPositionFromCharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getpositionfromcharindex.aspx) method in C#? I need to get the XY position of each hyperlink displayed in a multi-line JEditorPane.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need JTextComponent.modelToView()